# Numpy search for elements of an array in a subset

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have numpy arrays

```
a = np.array([1,3,5,7,9,11,13])
b = np.array([3,5,7,11,13])
```

and I want to create a boolean array of the size of a where each entry is True or False depending on whether the element of a is also in b.

So in this case, I want

```
a_b = np.array([False,True,True,True,False,True,True]).
```

I can do this when b consists of one element as a == b[0]. Is there a quick way to do this when b has length greater than 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`numpy.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
In [672]: np.in1d([1,2,3,4], [1,2])
Out[672]: array([ True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

For your data:

```
In [674]: np.in1d(a, b)
Out[674]: array([False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

This is available in version 1.4.0 or later according to the docs. The docs also describe how the operation might look in pure Python:

> `in1d` can be considered as an element-wise function version of the python keyword `in`, for 1-D sequences. `in1d(a, b)` is roughly equivalent to `np.array([item in b for item in a])`.

The docs for this function are worthwhile to read as there is the `invert` keyword argument and the `assume_unique` keyword argument -- each of which can be quite useful in some situations.

I also found it interesting to create my own version using `np.vectorize` and `operator.contains`:

```
from operator import contains
v_in = np.vectorize(lambda x,y: contains(y, x), excluded={1,})
```

and then:

```
In [696]: v_in([1,2,3, 2], [1, 2])
Out[696]: array([ True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Because `operator.contains` flips the arguments, I needed the `lambda` to make the calling convention match your use case -- but you could skip this if it was okay to call with `b` first then `a`.

But note that you need to use the `excluded` option for `vectorize` since you want whichever argument represents the `b` sequence (the sequence to check for membership within) to actually remain as a sequence (so if you chose not to flip the `contains` arguments with the `lambda` then you would want to exclude index `0` not `1`).

The way with `in1d` will surely be much faster and is a much better way since it relies on a well-known built-in. But it's good to know how to do these tricks with `operator` and `vectorize` sometimes.

You could even create a [Python Infix recipe instance](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/384122-infix-operators/) for this and then use `v_in` as an "infix" operation:

```
v_in = Infix(np.vectorize(lambda x,y: contains(y, x), excluded={1,}))
# even easier: v_in = Infix(np.in1d)
```

and example usage:

```
In [702]: v_in([1, 2, 3, 2], [1, 2])
Out[702]: array([ True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [704]: [1, 2, 3, 2] <<v_in>> [1, 2]
Out[704]: array([ True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I was going to use list comprehension if not for this.